# Conditional renaming of strings in Python

Tags: python, string

How do I create a conditional renaming of variable strings in Python?

Let's say I have:

```
fruit = "Apfel"
```

If it's "Apfel", I want to rename it to "`Apple`".

Alternatively, the variable may return a different string.

```
fruit = "Erdbeere"
```

If so, I want to rename it to "`Strawberry`".

Comment: After renaming save it to a `list`, in this way you can change the value of the variable and save the results in a list.

Comment: You can make a dict in which you will have strings that you can get and changed version of strings

Comment: Renaming on what basis? It it's rule based (straightforward word-to-word), dictionary lookup is the simplest.

Comment: @AdityaJoshi Basically I am doing a query from a German website. The variable returns one of a few different alternatives in German. Depending on what those are, I would like to rename them to strings of my choosing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to use a dictionary for this:

```
>>> translation = {'Apfel': 'Apple', 'Erdbeere' : 'Strawberry'}
>>> fruit = 'Apfel'
>>> translation[fruit]
'Apple'
>>> fruit = 'Erdbeere'
>>> translation[fruit]
'Strawberry'
```

You might also want to make sure that the translation exists:

```
>>> fruit = "Orange"
>>> translation[fruit]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Orange'
```

For example like this:

```
try:
    translated = translation[fruit]
except KeyError:
    print("Unknown translation for %s" % fruit)
```

Comment: @AdityaJoshi well there is only one obvious answer to this

Answer (score 9):

You need to prepare a dictionary in advance. Either use publicly available lexicons or invest some time building it.

```
fruit = "Apfel"
myDict = {"Apfel":"Apple", "Erdbeere":"Strawberry"}
fruit=myDict[fruit]
print fruit
```

Also take care if the word is or isn't capitalized.